# Error while creating first project with maven

Tags: maven, exception, build

I am trying to learn maven so following so following [Maven Guide](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/index.html#What_is_Maven). When trying to create the first project in windows D drive using following command

```
mvn -B archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes  
-DgroupId=com.mycompany.app -DartifactId=my-app
```

Build is getting failed.[image]

When I rerun the maven command with -e option for the full stack trace, It's showing ArrayIndexOutOfBound Exception.

[image]

can anyone help me in understanding what's causing this issue.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Part of the problem is that you're using the -B flag which means non-interactive (i.e. don't ask for more input) but then you don't supply enough input.
If you're just trying stuff then you could remove the -B flag and go with the interactive mode.

Comment: I have run the same command without -B option Still getting the same error.

Comment: I'm running the exact same cmd (without -B) using Maven 3.5.0. Are you using a different, older version? If so, perhaps you'd like to upgrade and try again.

Comment: Ahem, running the exact same cmd and _it is working for me_ .

Comment: I am also using maven 3.5.0. I also don't think that -B option is an issue as it's there in guide on official site of maven.

Comment: Then try using the `-X` option (i.e. a lot of debug text) and post the resulting output, perhaps we can see something strange.

Comment: It was very weird. I deleted the generated folders and files from .m2 directory and rerun the same command with -B option and now it's succeed. Anyways thanks for your help @Andrei.

Answer (score 0):

It was very weird. I deleted the generated folders and files from .m2 directory and rerun the same command with -B option and now it's succeed.